# Error in regular expression in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a problem with a regular expression in c #, I use regular expression in perl is this:

In Perl

```
if($code=~/[[["(.*)"/) {
}
```

In C#

```
Match regex = Regex.Match(code,"[[[\"(.*)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

the problem is that it appears error when I use "[[[", eh tried to avoid the error by using "\" but the problem is that the code is throwing the error as "["

anyone can help me?

Error : analizando "[[["(.*)"" - Conjunto [] sin terminar (In Spanish)

Comment: Stop editing all of your questions into gibberish.  It'll just end up rolled back.  You keeping this up will only ever result in your account being suspended, and your questions *still sticking around unvandalized*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use string [literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this, and you are escaping double quote with \, you need to escape double quote with a double quote too.

Try this:

```
Match regex = Regex.Match("test", @"[[[""(.*)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: To further explain: You need the C# string literal `@` because you want to treat \ as a character in the string rather than an escape sequence.

Comment: thanks for the help, but still throwing error : 

analizando "[[["(.*)"" - Conjunto [] sin terminar.